Evaluate a list in a Kogito DMN decision table
I have a Kogito decision table that receives a structure as input with the following format:
input = { "name": "Karl", "favourite_colour": "blue" }
and returns a decision based on the colour.
The single value scenario that works
Now I need to change this and accept the following input structure:
input = { "name: "Karl", "fauvourite_colours": [ "blue", "red" ] }
I have been unable to get such a simple scenario working.
I tried defining this DMN:
the DMN diagram
and testing it with this .scesim file:
the test
where I define the input list as:
the list
My tests are failing as per the message below. I think the expression that I defined to evaluate the elements of the list is not defined properly.
org.drools.scenariosimulation.backend.runner.IndexedScenarioAssertionError: #2 Blue + Blue: Failed in "MultipleValues": The expected value is ""Everton"" but the actual one is ""Other"" (MultipleValueTest)
Any help much appreciated.

The problem in your second DMN decision table is that you didn't use the extended unary test, and the "extended" variant is needed since you want to apply an expression rather than a simple unary test.
Try replacing with:
every item in ? satisfies item = "blue"

Where the ? is a placeholder of the "what is coming as input in the column".

Thank you, your answer works and my tests pass in the scesim file. However, when I try to run this from outside the test (an API call) it doesn't. My rule does not match. I presume it has to do with the fact that the scesim editor defines the param list as a string [{"value":""blue""},{"value":""red""}]. The actual colours are nested inside an object. Is this the way I need to do it? When I try to execute the rule through an API, do I need to provide a list of strings or a list of objects with the strings nested into a "value" property?

What you have in the original Question is correct. A list with string values, no need of "object to hold the value". I.e. ["blue", ...] is valid for DMN to be a list of string literals.

That works perfectly. Thanks a lot @tarilabs.

glad to help :)
